# JavaScript function document.addEventListener not working

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, addeventlistener

I'm creating a basic Flask application.  Below is a snipped of my .py file.  The check_for_event() is just a dummy function for now meant to toggle 'flag' for testing purposes.  When 'flag' is set True, my '/update' route is changing my result.

```
app = Flask(__name__)

flag = False
def check_for_event():
    global flag
    for i in range(10):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            flag = True
            time.sleep(5)
        else:
            flag = False
            time.sleep(2)

@app.route('/update', methods=['GET'])
def update_data():
    global flag
    my_array = []
    if flag:
        flag = False
        my_array.append([str(randrange(1000)), "Place_Holder_1", "Place_Holder_2"])
        # Dispatch the 'resultChange' event along with the updated 'result'
        updated_result = {'type': 'resultChange', 'result': my_array}
    else:
        # If there's no change, send a 'noChange' event
        updated_result = {'type': 'noChange'}
    return jsonify(updated_result)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    t = Thread(target = check_for_event)
    t.start()
    app.run()
```

Below is a snipped of my HTML/JavaScript.  I've added an event listener to detect a change, and trigger a function call, to do other things.  I've added some print statements, but I'm never getting inside the event listener.  My overall goal here is for updateAndDisplayResult() only to execute when updated_result is populated with an update to my_array[] in update_data().

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
// Function to update and display the 'result'
function updateAndDisplayResult() {
    // Handle result from main.py
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/update', function(data) {      
        if (data.result.length > 0) {
          // Do Something...
        }
    }); // end of getJSON()
}; // end of updateAndDisplayResult

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  // Event listener for custom event 'result_change'
  document.addEventListener('result_change', function(event) {
    var my_event = event.detail;
    console.log("Inside Event Listener");
    
    if (my_event.type === 'resultChange') {
      console.log("Result Changed!");
      updateAndDisplayResult();
    }
  });
});

</script>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome!</h1>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
```

Edit:
A user pointed out that I'm missing a dispatchEvent() call to fire this event.  This must be the issue or at least a very big part of my problem.  I think I need to add something like this:

```
var resultChangeEvent = new CustomEvent('result_change'); 
document.dispatchEvent(resultChangeEvent);
```

I tried a few variations, but still no luck.  Can anyone help?

Comment: The snippet you shared shows you subscribing to the custom_event 'result_change', but you don't have any code that actually fires the event (i.e. `dispatchEvent`) see [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-custom-events/#)

Comment: Looks like I missed a big part of this.  Seems like I have to add something like this: var resultChangeEvent = new CustomEvent('result_change');
document.dispatchEvent(resultChangeEvent);       I'm still not too sure where this would go and if it's even correct/complete.  Any more details?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you only want to update the output on the client side when new data is available. Have you considered using [Flask-SocketIO](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to notify clients of new data when it has changed?